# (En) ce matin doux et brumeux

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

*L'escargot* de Paul Starosta :

> **En** ce matin doux et brumeux, l'escargot ne mange plus, il cherche un
> compagnon.

Quelle est la différence entre "en ce matin" et "ce matin" ?

Answer (score 3):

Quand on entend une phrase qui commence par ***Ce matin doux et brumeux***, on s'attend à ce que la suite parle du matin lui-même, par exemple ***il restera gravé dans ma mémoire***.

Quand une phrase commence par ***En ce matin doux et brumeux***, on est sûr que la suite va parler de quelque chose qui s'est passé au cours de ce matin-là, par exemple ***mon escargot tourne en rond***.

Le sens de *en* est proche de *durant, au cours de, pendant, lors de, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

« Ce matin » est  le plus souvent  une expression figée qui désigne le matin du jour pendant lequel le locuteur s'exprime. On ne pourrait pas dire « ce matin doux et brumeux » dans ce cas. Le fait d'ajouter « en » annule l'idée de matin du jour où on parle et fait du matin un matin situé n'importe quand mais  qui peut quand même être celui du jour où on parle ; c'est un usage littéraire, dans la langue parlé oon dit  « [dans/pendant/au cours de] cette matinée ». Pour référer à un autre matin on utilise « ce matin-là » (locution figée). Il y a une difficulté à bien comprendre. Dans l'explication qui vient d'être donnée, l'adjectif démonstratif pronominal « ce » ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectif_pronominal)) n'a pas de remplacement textuel, et c'est la raison pour laquelle « ce matin » a un référent particulier qui est le matin du jour où le locuteur s'exprime. Il est possible de changer le contexte et de fournir un remplacement textuel, et alors l'expression figée est annulée.

*jour où on parle*

- Ce matin j'ai commencé à lire *L'idiot* et je n'ai pas arrêté jusqu'à la fin de l'après-midi ; maintenant, après avoir pris un repas je vais me remettre à la lecture de cette œuvre et vais la prolonger jusqu'à onze heures ou minuit.
- <s>En ce matin j'ai commencé…</s>

*jour quelconque*

- C'était il y a quelques temps et le jour  venait de se lever ; **en ce matin** doux et brumeux, l'escargot ne mange plus, il cherche un compagnon.
- C'était il y a quelques temps et le jour  venait de se lever ; **ce matin-là**, qui était doux et brumeux, l'escargot ne mange plus, il cherche un compagnon.

Noter que « ce matin-là doux et brumeux » n'est pas possible parce que « ce matin-là » est une expression figée ; donc, « matin » ne peut pas être sujet à une modification par un adjectif.

*« ce matin » avec un remplacement textuel pour « ce »*

- C'était un jour  de l'année dernière, après nous être levés, vers huit heures.  **Ce matin** ne s'effacera jamais de ma mémoire ; nous marchions sur une route déserte en Turquie lorsque le sol s'est mis à trembler et a très vite  commencé à se crevasser ; un trou béant se trouvait à quelques mètres alors que le sol sur lequel nous étions tombés prenait de plus en plus de pente vers le trou. (*Comme le temps de l'évènement est mentionné (après huit heures) on comprends que « ce » indique que le matin est celui auquel il est fait référence en d'autres termes dans les mots qui précèdent, c'est à dire en termes de  moment situé aux environs de huit heures.*)
- C'est arrivé ce matin, j'ai reçu une lettre qui m'annonce que le prix m'a été decerné. Je te téléphone maintenant parce que je n'ai pas eu le temps, il n'y a qu'en cette fin d'aprés-midi que je n'ai plus à répondre au téléphone. Je crois pouvoir te dire que ce matin aura été le plus heureux de toute ma vie. (*Il existe dans cette énonciation une coexistence de deux assignations de fonction possible à « ce matin », ce qui fait qu'un locuteur pourra préférer utiliser « cette matinée » ou « c'est un matin qui » en vue de supprimer l'effet désagréable (cette matinée aura été la plus heureuse de toute ma vie).*)

Comment: Merci beaucoup. // _Noter que « ce matin-là doux et brumeux » n'est pas possible_ --- Est-il possible d'écrire _C'était il y a quelques temps et le jour venait de se lever ; **ce matin-là, doux et brumeux,** l'escargot ne mange plus, il cherche un compagnon._, _doux et brumeux_ encadré par des virgules ?

Comment: @Oreste Pour être consistant, puisque je trouve  la modification par une relative descriptive normal (ce matin-là, qui était doux et brumeux), je devrais trouver tout aussi normal la modifiication par des adjectif apposés. Votre question me fait douter, cependant. Il me semble que oui, mais je vais essayer de voir si je trouve des confirmations.

Comment: Merci, je crois que _Ce matin-là, **doux et brumeux**, l'escargot ne mange plus, il cherche un compagnon_ devrait aussi être correct, selon toute vraisemblance.

Comment: @Oreste J'ai trouvé un exemple, ce qui n'est pas beaucoup ; je le place chez Cosette.

Comment: @LPH Attention: "consistant" n'a pas le sens de l'anglais *consistent* et s'utilise par exemple pour qualifier un plat ou un repas, ce que tu n'es vraisemblablement pas. En français : "Pour être cohérent,..."

Comment: @jlliagre Il est presque certain que j'utilise « consistant » en raison de l'influence de l'anglais ; cependant, d'après le TLFi, on peut encore l'utiliser comme synonyme de « cohérent »  :  [lien](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consistant) b) [En parlant de choses] Qui a de la consistance (cf. II A et B), de la cohérence et de la stabilité; sur quoi on peut se fonder. Synon. fondé, réel, sûr, tangible.Bruit, projet consistant.

Comment: Tu es donc une "chose"...

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, d'accord, c'est mal employé dans ma phrase. Je n'aurais pas voulu dire que j'étais cohérent, mais que la chose devait l'être. Merci des remarques.

Comment: @jlliagre Antidote : consistant : FIGURÉ – Solide, cohérent. _Une démonstration consistante. Une rumeur consistante._ (notion abstraite) // être consistant dans quelque chose
Calque. — QUÉBEC – On écrit plutôt être cohérent dans quelque chose, être logique dans quelque chose ou être conséquent dans quelque chose.

Comment: @Oreste Oui, je connais bien les sens du mot consistant en français. Je doute que ce soit sous l'influence d'un anglicisme québécois que LPH a fait cette erreur, vu son manque d'intérêt et d'empathie pour le français qui y est parlé. La confusion entre cohérent et consistant est en progression mais rend les phrases inintelligibles pour qui ne connais pas l'anglais, ou le connais mal. [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=consistant&id=3294)